# Postgres select rows where ANY in a given array = ANY in column array

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, I need to select all rows where any value in an array (passed as variable) is equal to any value in the column (that is also an array). This means something like this:

```
SELECT * 
from table 
where ANY (value_in_an_array_variable) = ANY (value_in_a_column_array);
```

If there is no direct way what's the best alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) ("have elements in common") operator:

```
select *
from some_table
where array_column && array[1,2,3];
```